# Json deserialize list of objects and save to DB

Tags: php, json

im trying to insert Json with this format into DB.

```
 {  
     "firstName": "Brett"
 }
```

This format is inserting properly.

But if i change the format like below:

```
 [  
 {  
  "firstName": "Brett"
 },
 {
 "firstName": "John"
 }
]
```

For the below script i could insert only 1st record.

```
<?php

 $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
 /*Server credentials*/
 $arraykey=array_keys($data); 
 $array=$data[$arraykey[0]]; 
 try 
 {
   //SQL Server execute
  foreach($data as $array)
  {
      $count = $dbh->exec("INSERT INTO table(firstname) VALUES ('" . implode("', '", $array) . "')" ) or die(print_r($dbh->errorInfo(), true)); 
    echo count($data);                                                                                                                      
    $dbh = null;
    echo 'Data Successfully inserted!!<br />';
   }
 }
catch(PDOException $e)
{
  echo $e->getMessage();
 }
```

How to insert all the json records for the above script.

Comment: you need to loop through your array, here you only fetch and process `$data[0]` ...

Comment: Loop through data like this
`foreach($data as $array){
  $count = $dbh->exec("INSERT INT................;
}`

Comment: Have updated the code@Hussain, when i say echo count , it still shows 1 record inserted with Fatal error: Call to a member function exec() on a non-object

Comment: Remove this line: `$dbh = null;` of your loop. That's the problem.

Comment: oh ok correct, i had given the echo as $count instead of echo count($data)..Data is inserting fine ..thanks